# Swipe on windows 7 touch screen rotates the screen

Tags: windows-7, display, touchscreen, orientation

I have a touch screen monitor with Windows 7 machine. A weird thing is if I swipe fast left to right or vice versa it rotates the screen by 90 degrees (change screen orientation from landscape to portrait mode).

First, it's odd enough that just a gesture does that but how can I disable that?

Here is a [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/383519/laptop-screen-is-suddenly-rotated/383531) but my problem is it is triggered by touch screen gesture.

Comment: Try disabling screen rotation in display settings.

Comment: @vembutech I can't find such option, how can I do that?